# how to switch next pages automatically after few seconds using nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, settimeout

```
//written in javascript
<script>
  setTimeout(function () {
     // after 2 seconds
     window.location = "/next-page";
  }, 2000)
</script>
//nodejs
app.get('/thankyou',function(req,res){
    res.render('thankyou' {message : 'Thank you for your submission'});
});
```

1)how to swith next pages automatically  after few seconds using nodejs
2)whenever i run the server it should go to the main page after few seconds automatically goes to next page

Answer (score 0):

Either you can mark window.location = '/thankyou' or change the router at nodejs side to '/next-page'

```
window.location = "/thankyou";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```js
// node.js:
app.get('/thankyou',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/redirect.html");
});

// redirect.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location = "/the-page";
            },2000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: printing this "path/to/redirect.html". not rendering to next page

Comment: Sorry, it should be sendFile

Comment: Please see the latest version.

Comment: app.use('/the-page',()=>
{
    res.send("<h1>welcome to second page</h1>")
})
going to second page but not displaying  content

Comment: Display nothing?

Comment: You should set arguments in the brackets like "(req,res,next)=>{"

Comment: no need to write next, it will work without that. iam using app.get

Comment: if u have system , please try once

Comment: i tried its working , going to second page. if i want to go second page third page what should i do

Comment: You mean goto the third page after going to the second page?